# display issue with folium related to longitude -180 to 180?

Tags: pandas, geometry, geopandas, folium

geometry overlay of the folium map is the opposite way of what I am trying to do. How do I change it?
How can an manage to make it work ?
is there another way to do it or even another tool than folium ?

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import folium 
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import transform
from functools import partial
import pyproj


def circle(lon):
    lat=0
    radius = 12756000
    local_azimuthal_projection = "+proj=aeqd +R=6378000 +units=m +lat_0={} +lon_0={}".format(lat, lon)
    wgs84_to_aeqd = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection))
    aeqd_to_wgs84 = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection), pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

    center = Point(float(lon), float(lat))
    point_transformed = transform(wgs84_to_aeqd, center)
    buffer = point_transformed.buffer(radius/1.4, resolution=64)
    circle_poly = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84, buffer)
    elevation=LineString(list(circle_poly.exterior.coords))
    return elevation

elevation = circle(100)
test = pd.DataFrame({'geometry':[elevation]})
test =gpd.GeoDataFrame(test , geometry='geometry', crs="EPSG:4326")

m = folium.Map(control_scale=True)
tooltip=folium.GeoJson(test , name='circle').add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

**Here's the output:**

[image]

Can someone please help me to show the right of the circle on the right (and not on the left)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! I am trying to run your code, but there's some parts missing. For example `from functools import partial` and `import pyproj`. Could you please provide a [mre] which I can run?

Comment: Hi yes indeed I forgot the import part.import pandas as pd\n",
    "import geopandas as gpd\n",
    "import folium\n",
    "from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LineString\n",
    "from shapely.ops import transform\n",
    "from functools import partial\n",
    "import pyproj

Comment: Maybe you can update the question with the edit button?

Comment: I sent in an edit for the question. Hopefully it will update soon. Thanks for the dependencies; now I'm able to run the code. I will take a look and maybe I can figure out an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of the ranges `latitude between -90 and +90` and `longitude between -180 and 180`:

[image]

**I would recommend the following code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import folium 
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import transform
from functools import partial
import pyproj


def circle(lon, lat):
    radius = 1275600
    local_azimuthal_projection = "+proj=aeqd +R=6378000 +units=m +lat_0={} +lon_0={}".format(lat, lon)
    wgs84_to_aeqd = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"), pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection))
    aeqd_to_wgs84 = partial(pyproj.transform, pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection), pyproj.Proj("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"))

    center = Point(float(lon), float(lat))
    point_transformed = transform(wgs84_to_aeqd, center)
    buffer = point_transformed.buffer(radius/1.4, resolution=64)
    circle_poly = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84, buffer)
    elevation=LineString(list(circle_poly.exterior.coords))
    return elevation

elevation = circle(0, 0)
test = pd.DataFrame({'geometry':[elevation]})
test =gpd.GeoDataFrame(test , geometry='geometry', crs="EPSG:4326")

m = folium.Map(control_scale=True)
tooltip=folium.GeoJson(test , name='circle').add_to(m)
folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
m
```

The changes are just to the input of `circle(long, lat)`, and the `radius` which is smaller.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you thenarfer for your answer. But the radius has to be the same as I put it first. And the longitude is the only parameters that change. So if you said that we can not do anything or parameters change on folium to change the-180 to 180 I guess I can not do what I want to. Do you or someone else have another answer or another way to do it ?